# Is my transaction code causing lock_wait_timeout error?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

as there are two possible way to implement transactions in codeigniter:

> 1.automatic
>
> 2.manual

`I am getting an error like :Lock_wait_timeout` in my codeigniter application.I don't have any wrong query in my code.But i found that i have wrote transaction code for automatic transaction similar to manual transaction.

as automatic transaction uses trans_start() ,on the other hand manual transaction uses trans_begin().

***For manual transaction codeigniter uses the following syntax***

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
insert query...
update query...

if($this->db->trans_status()===FALSE){

   $this->db->trans_rollback();
}else{
   $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

***But i have used automatic transaction in my code,and  wrote it like the following(used if else statement like manual transaction):***

```
 $this->db->trans_start();
    insert query...
    update query...
 $this->db->trans_complete();
    if($this->db->trans_status()===FALSE){

       $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }else{
       $this->db->trans_commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `trans_complete()` does almost exactly the same thing as your if/else statement as it makes a call to either `trans_rollback()` or `trans_commit()` as appropriate. Undoubtedly your second attempt at commit or rollback is greatly confusing your database. Just remove your if/else and all should be good.